# Spinner and HashTable in android

Tags: android, hashtable, spinner

I need to implement a spinner, but instead of loading its content from an array I need to use a HashTable's values so that when the user selects an entry, I get the corresponding key.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple.
you need to just make the object for hash map an add it to the array list.
then after reflect that array list object where ever you are needed.

e.g.
ArrayList> list;
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.put("key","value");
list.add(hm);